# Promise rejection: No provider for UserDetails! (UserDetails is Model class)

Tags: api, angular, http

I am trying to get Session data, using http get in Service-GlobalServiceService's GetSessionData() method and in my Component-HeaderComponent, I am subscribing to response from GetSessionData() and then assigning to object of type UserDetails which is a model class .
Service-

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { UserDetails } from "app/model/UserDetails";
@Injectable()
export class GlobalServiceService {
    constructor(private lohttp: Http, private loAuthService : AuthService) { }
GetSessionData(): Observable<UserDetails[]>
{
  return  this.lohttp.get('http://localhost:49609/api/Authentication/checkUserSession')
     .map((res:Response) => res.json()
     .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error ||  'Server 
error'))
     );    
}
}
```

Component-

```
import { GlobalServiceService } from './../services/global-service.service';
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    lsUserName: string;
     lsUserDetails:UserDetails[];
    constructor(private loAuthService: AuthService,private loGlobalService: 
GlobalServiceService,private userDetails:UserDetails) { }
     LoadSessionData()
    {
     this.loGlobalService.GetSessionData()
         .subscribe(
                    data => this.lsUserDetails = data, 
                    err => { console.log(err);}
                    );
    }
 ngOnInit() {
        this.LoadSessionData();
    }
}
```

I am new to angular 2. I can't understand why its showing errors like below even when I have imported :

```
1.ERROR Error: No provider for UserDetails!
    at injectionError (core.es5.js:1232) [angular]
    ...
View_AppComponent_0 @ AppComponent.html:2
proxyClass @ compiler.es5.js:13560
...
2. zone.js:569 Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for UserDetails! ; 

3. Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No provider for 
UserDetails!
    at injectionError (core.es5.js:1232) [angular]
4.zone.js:571 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for 
UserDetails!
```

--->When UserDetails added to imports in app.module.ts it gave foll error

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'UserDetails' imported by the module
>   'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
>       at syntaxError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:44937:34) []

Comment: If `private userDetails:UserDetails` is a model class it cant be injected through the constructor.. that is why you are getting the error

Comment: Oh thanks Suraj. I got it worked.

Comment: I have One more question  to ask.
A call component to API via Service is executed first and call from component directly to API gets executed second ?
Why So?
Can I Sequence the calls to API?
 If yes please tell me how many ways I can do it?

Comment: that could depend on which page and whether it is lazy loaded and also on whether the service is singleton...

Comment: not sure what you mean by sequence the calls.. you can chain calls using promises/observables in service/component... But it is better to do it in service and leave view handling to the component

Comment: Thanks I will go through your suggestions.
I cant see option to mark your answer as accepted answer

Comment: thats because I put in comments.. wait I will add my original comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `UserDetails` is a *model*, you cannot inject it in the constructor.

```
 constructor(private loAuthService: AuthService,private loGlobalService: 
GlobalServiceService,private userDetails:UserDetails)
```

Remove this -> `private userDetails:UserDetails` in *HeaderComponent*.